# Can''t resolve CreateJsonReader

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I inherited some VB.NET code that has the following:

```
xmlreader = Json.CreateJsonReader(result, quotas)
```

I can't seem to resolve this reference. MSDN tells me its in `System.Runtime.Serilaization.Json` but if I type that with Intellisense I don't get to a Json namespace or the function. What am I doing wrong?

It's also barfing on these two statements before it saying I should switch to something else:

```
 Dim xmlreader As System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader
 Dim quotas As New System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
```

Comment: I tried that but It still doesn't show up in that namespace.

Comment: what version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: VS2013 with it set to .NET Framework 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may be looking for a method on the [JsonReaderWriterFactory class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory.createjsonreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
xmlreader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(result, quotas)
```

No `new` keyword is required in this case because you aren't instantiating anything: you're calling a static method, but that method is on the `JsonReaderWriterFactory`, not a class called `Json`.